# Angular2 Sending data in as a key to EXPRESS in POST method

Tags: angular

I'm sending data to express server through the Angular2 But getting data in a crazy way. But it is working well with the Postman.

Angular2 code is:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
  private _options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) });
  constructor(private _http: Http){ }
  login(credentials: Object){
    return this._http.post('/api/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), this._options);
  }
}
```

Gettin data in express is like:

```
{ '{"username":"XXXXXXXX","password":"XXXXXXXX"}': '' }
```

But when sending data in postman getting as expected

```
{"username":"XXXXXXXX","password":"XXXXXXXX"}
```

Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're stringifying the data:

```
return this._http.post('/api/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), this._options);
```

Instead do this:

```
return this._http.post('/api/login', credentials, this._options);
```

Comment: It's not the problem.. That doesn't make any issues. It's problem with Angular2 http package

Comment: Can you post your express route too? I made a similar call yesterday and it worked just fine.